# How optimizing cartesian product query in SQL

Tags: sql, query-optimization, cartesian-product

I query a cartesian product over several tables in SQL.

If I query

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1, TABLE2, ... , TABLE n   WHERE ....
```

it may be fast.

It gives, let me say, only 1-3 hits.

Now, if I query more tables,

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1, TABLE2, ... , TABLE n, TABLE n+1, ..., TABLE m   WHERE ....
```

it breaks down by slowlyness.

Why? Does sql go through all combinations by beginning with the last table?

My Question for optimization:

Should I choose TABLE 1 as the table which will narrow and filter the search most, or the last TABLE m?

Or what else?

Comment: You don't *optimize* a cartesian product - you **avoid** it! :-)

Comment: If you are applying `WHERE` conditions, it is not a pure cartesian product any more. How do your conditions look like?

Comment: Also see: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](sqlblog.com/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins.aspx) - this also helps a lot when avoiding unwanted cartesian products!

Comment: I agree with marc_s - either you want a cartesian product (which seems unlikely - the number of rows will be the product of all row counts of the involved tables), or you don't want it (which is true in > 99% of all cases).

Comment: *Mark Byers* : MySQL -- Thank you for all comments, which already help. *Frank Schmitt*: Indeed. The hits go rapidely down with each table. -- My idea was this. With each table more, the cases reduces rapidly. Lets say, each table reduces to 1/1000 of the cases. So I have to check only (1/1000)^n cases. --- *marc_s*: thanks. --- I will check this post out.

Answer (score 3):

Your title says it all - cartesian product. Unless you specify join conditions between the various tables, the database server will try to produce **EVERY** combination of records possible. As you add tables, this grows very quickly, e.g. 5 tables with 10 = 10^5, 100,000 records.

You need to use proper join techniques (left,right,inner) join clauses to narrow down the record set.

Comment: Thank you, I did not know that JOIN helps.

Comment: But will it be faster? Is INNER JOIN faster then "WHERE table1.ID = table2.POINTER_TO_ID" ?

Comment: definitely. it won't have to retrieve your n^m record combinations, only the ones that fit the join conditions.

Comment: #Marc B: Ok. Although it is not quite clear for me. If it selects ID in the first table, then it also has to *search* the row in the second table with POINTER_TO_ID = ID, isn't it? Or does SQL have more information behind to avoid this search.

Comment: I have a empirical conjecture: if you query cartesian product (table 1,...,table n) with WHERE conditions, then make no forward reference: WHERE ID(table 1)= DATA(table 2) is ok, but the other direction (1 <--> 2) is inefficient.

Comment: no, I must revise. I think this conjecture is not really true.

Answer (score 0):

Join several tables is very slow already at 3 tables too.
A solution can be a some multiplication of the selects

something like that:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1, 
  (SELECT * FROM TABLE2, 
     (SELECT * FROM TABLE3, 
        (..)
      WHERE ..) 
   WHERE .. )
WHERE
 ...
```

Comment: Yes indeed, this would also be my option. Because the first select gives only 3 hits and is very fast. Why does it then take so much time "selecting" from this 3 cases further. This was also my question.

Comment: probably the latest tables are too long. your version concatenates all of the rows and from them selects the three hits. but if selection will taken particularly by table to table, then will appear only a few row per parantheses

Comment: thanks. I agree. Your suggestion was also my worst case scenario solution when SQL cannot handle it with cartesian product or Inner join.